# It is necessary that the collection of supports cover the manifold for defining a finite sum?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am reading an introduction to manifolds second edition by Loring W. Tu and a strong concern arose me regarding the following remark that is developed on page 146:

*Suppose {$f_\alpha $}$_{\alpha \in A}$ is a collection of smooth functions on a manifold $M$ such that
the collection of its supports, $S$={supp $f_\alpha $}$_{\alpha \in A}$, is locally finite. **Then every point q in $M$ has a neighborhood $W_q$ that intersects supp $f_\alpha $ for only finitely many $\alpha$**. Thus, on $W_q$ only finitely many of the $f_\alpha$'s can be nonzero and the sum $\sum_{\alpha \in A}f_\alpha$ is actually a finite sum. This shows that the function $f=\sum f_\alpha$ is well defined and smooth on the manifold $M$.*

I can't understand the marked part. Isn't the hypothesis necessary that for every point $q\in M$ there exists $\alpha$ such that $f_\alpha \neq0$?. In this case, I can prove the marked part easily taking on M the open set $f_\alpha ^{-1}(V_q)$, where $V_q$ is an open interval about $q$ whitout $0$, and using the hypothesis $S$ is locally finite.

Is it my hypothesis necessary or I'm wrong and the remark is done?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your additional hypothesis, that the supports cover the manifold, is not needed. Zero is a perfectly good finite number, so it's perfectly OK for a point $q$ to have a neighborhood $W_q$ that intersects none of the supports. The sum of the $f_\alpha$'s will then reduce, in that neighborhood, to an empty sum, whose value is $0$.

The sentence that you quoted in bold type in the question is just the definition of "locally finite", which was assumed in the preceding sentence.

Comment: Is right!. I'm so embarrassed, I was replaying this definition wrong in my head